# Field that contains $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, field-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. There exists a field $F$ that contains an isomorphic copy of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ as a multiplicative subgroup?

Clearly if $n=1$ we can take $F=\mathbb{F}_p$, but for $n>1$ ?

Comment: $(\mathbf{Z}/p^n\mathbf{Z})^{*}$ is cyclic of order $p^{n-1}(p-1)$. Would a subgroup of $\mathbf{C}^{*}$ do the trick?

Comment: Per chance you should specify that you want to prove the assertion without the cyclic assumption.

Comment: I made another (yet unsuccessful) attempt, and asked a [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934622/is-the-embedding-problem-with-a-cyclic-kernel-always-solvable).

Answer (score 5):

I assume $p$ is an odd prime.

The order of $(\mathbb{Z} / p^n)^*$ is $(p-1)p^{n-1}$. You can decompose it as the direct sum of the subgroup of $(p-1)$-th roots of unity and the group of elements that are $1 \bmod p$.

We can define the logarithm function on the latter group as

$$ \log(1 + x) \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{x^i}{i} \pmod{p^n}$$

This is really a finite sum, because by assumption $p \mid x$, and for sufficiently large $i$ we have $p^i / i \equiv 0 \pmod{p^n}$. And well-defined mod $p^n$, because the power of $p$ in the numerator is always at least as much as the power of $p$ in the denominator.

By doing the tedious calculations with power series, you can show $\log$ is a homomorphism from the multiplicative group of elements that are $1 \bmod p$ to the additive group of elements that are $0 \bmod p$.

Incidentally, you can define its inverse $\exp$ in the same way, as the series

$$ \exp(x) \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} \pmod{p^n} $$

Thus, $(\mathbb{Z} / p^n)^*$ is cyclic, and thus can be embedded in any field with a primitive $p^n(p-1)$-th root of unity.

Answer (score 2):

According to Theorem 22 in section 1.6 in [this note by Pete L. Clark,](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400FULL.pdf) the group $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^*$ is cyclic, when $p$ is an odd prime. Hence we can answer your question affirmatively:
Just take the algebraic closure $K$ of $\mathbb Q,$ then $K$ contains all solutions of the equation $$x^{p^n-p^{n-1}}-1=0,$$ which is a cyclic group of the same order as $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^*,$ and so $K$ suffices for our prupose.
P.S. It suffices to take, for a given $n,$ the splitting field of the equation in question over $\mathbb Q.$
Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question. Unfortunately I was looking for an alternative proof of the fact that  $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^*$ is cyclic. Do you think we can avoid using that fact?

Comment: I tried to embed the group into a field only under the assumption of the abelian-ness of the group, but to no avail, so I ask [a new question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930729/can-every-anelian-group-be-embedded-in-a-field) In fact, I think a genral abelian group might not be able to be embedded in a field, so that we must more or less employ of the special properties of the group in question here to successfully embed it.

Comment: You're right, a general finite abelian group can not be embedded in a field, otherwise that would imply the group to be cyclic... But your question remains interesting if the group is infinite.

Comment: Oh! I was so silly! Sorry for asking that bizarre question then. And I shall ponder more upon the question. Thanks for pointing it out, then.