# Showing $x^2 = 1\pmod{p^{\alpha}}$ has only two solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

In the $p | x - 1$ case, I'm a little confused about some of the latter steps; in particular, how does knowing that

$$\exists y \ s.t. (x+1)y \equiv 1\pmod{p^{\alpha}}$$

tell us that

$$(x^2 - 1)y \equiv 0\pmod{p^{\alpha}}$$

and how does this simplify to

$$x - 1 \equiv 0\pmod{p^{\alpha}}?$$

Thanks.

Comment: The quoted proof is surprisingly awful, so to be confused is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I feel the proof is formulated a bit awkwardly; some of the implications are, as you stated, not quite clear.

In your first two congruences, you do not actually need $y$. The existence of your $y$ is merely a side-product of the statement that $x+1$ and $p^\alpha$ are coprime.

This does not immediately yield $p^\alpha|(x^2-1)y$. Note that in your proof the line is "In this case, if $(x^2-1)y=0 \mod p^\alpha$, ..."

So this is another assumption - it is actually equivalent to your proposition (since $GCD(y,p)=1$).

To gain $x-1|p^\alpha$, we need the above fact that $GCD(y,p^\alpha)=GCD(x+1,p^\alpha)=1$.

Using that, the relation $p^\alpha|(x^2-1)=(x+1)(x-1)y$ simplifies directly to $p^\alpha|x-1$, which is what you want to show.

Frankly, looking at your proof, I am not entirely sure what the point of introducing $y$ is. It doesn't hurt, sure, but I cannot see how it makes anything easier, either.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternative proof, using some algebra:
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929821/field-that-contains-mathbbz-pn-mathbbz/929827#929827), the multiplicative group of units modulo $p^n$ can always be embedded in a field, and an equation with degree $k$ and coefficients in a field has at most $k$ solutions in that field. Q.E.D.
Hope this helps.